# Ngb installation error on my Angular application

Tags: angular

I'm trying to follow along this tutorial on Ngb: https://medium.com/@sunilk/getting-started-angular-6-and-ng-bootstrap-4-4b314e015c1c
And just trying to install the package gives me errors during compile time.

This is the error that the browser console is returning with:
Failed to compile.

```
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/<my username>/Documents/dlc-website/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
```

I had to install a previous version because the latest is not stable:
`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

I'm just trying to use Ngb so that I can use the carousel component on my web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of older versions of rxjs.

Try installing rxjs-compat: `npm install rxjs-compat`